# How can I bind the VSCode refactor "Move to file" to a hotkey without selecting between the two options

Tags: visual-studio-code

The following shortcut works, except that it makes be choose between move to *new* file and move to an existing file.

```
  {
    "key": "F6",
    "command": "editor.action.codeAction",
    "args": {
      "kind": "refactor.move"
    }
  }
```

I can append `.new` to `refactor.move` to make it always move the symbol to a *new* file, but I can't figure out how to get it to choose the second option (Move to existing file) in the dropdown by default.

How can I create a shortcut for moving a symbol to an existing file in VSCode, which doesn't require me to choose between the "New File" and "Existing File" options

Comment: what programming language and what language support extension are you talking about? pretty sure this varies by language support extension. https://github.com/search?q=kind+%22refactor.move.new%22&type=code